# Programming Assignment: Object-Oriented Sets: def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet, Blows my Mind

Tags: scala, oop

It seems that i am in a dead-end!
Alright this is a programming assignment that i have almost done BUT i have stuck for some days in an enormous problem!

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {

    if(p(elem))
        acc.incl(elem)

    if(!(left isEmpty))
        left filterAcc(p, acc)

    if(!(right isEmpty))
        right filterAcc(p, acc)

    acc
}
```

After many println's and debugging it seems that acc.incl(elem) Doesn't seem to work! I don't know why but it doesn't add elements.
I call this like:

```
 def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = filterAcc(p, new Empty)
```

Again this is from the Programming Assignment: Object-Oriented Sets in Scala.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `acc` is immutable. `acc.incl` will not change the existing instance, it will create a new instance with the additional `elem`.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are assuming that the `incl` method mutates the `TweetSet`. As the assignment looks like is from Principles of Functional Programming in Scala, I would expect the `TweetSet` type to be immutable, hence you would have to alter your current implementation.

To have a parallel on immutable data structure, think about strings: if you call the `reverse` method on a string, it doesn't causes that same instance to come out reversed, but rather it creates a new string that is reversed.

```
scala> val s = "hello, world"
s: String = hello, world

scala> val r = s.reverse
r: String = dlrow ,olleh

scala> println(s, r)
(hello, world,dlrow ,olleh)
```

Answer (score 1):

TweetSet is a inmutable set, acc.incl(elem) will return a new TweetSet, and the acc will keep unchanged.

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
  if (p(elem)) {
    right.filterAcc(p, left.filterAcc(p, acc.incl(elem)))
  } else {
    right.filterAcc(p, left.filterAcc(p, acc))
  }
}
```

Comment: how can you call a recursive function without base case? p.s i guess i have my answer: calling filteracc on empty should return empty()

Answer (score 0):

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    right.filterAcc(p, left.filterAcc(p, if (p(elem)) acc.incl(elem) else acc))
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.